# TYPO3 v8 QueryBuilder WHERE IN statement

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, typo3

Im trying to use a `WHERE IN`statement for the QueryBuilder.
I want to call

```
UPDATE tx_test SET hidden = 0 WHERE uid IN (1,2,3,4)
```

my code:

```
    public function makeItemsVisible($itemsToShow)
    {
        $itemUids = implode(",", $itemsToShow);
        $table = 'tx_test';
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
            ->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
        $queryBuilder
            ->update($table)
            ->set('hidden', "0")
            ->where('uid IN (:uids)')
            ->setParameter('uids', $itemUids )
            ->execute();
    }
```

The $itemUids `1,2,3,4` are correct, but the statement is only updating the first record in the Database. Do I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the expression builder and the API to add named parameters:

```php
$queryBuilder
  ->update($table)
  ->set('hidden', 0)
  ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in(
      'uid',
      $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($itemUids, Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
  )
  ->execute();
```

See the [*Comparisons* section](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/ExpressionBuilder/Index.html#comparisons) in the `ExpressionBuilder` documentation for details.

Comment: i cannot find PARAM_INT_ARRAY inside Connection class anymore? what has changed here?

Comment: It's still defined in the TYPO3 `Connection` which extends the Doctrine DBAL `Connection`, see https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.0.x/src/Connection.php#L46