# How to write a "where in" clause in the TYPO3 query builder?

Tags: typo3

I want to use a sql clausethat goes like "WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid_local FROM table)". How would you translate that into the querybuilder or is there a way to just use literal sql(kind of like with addselectliteral?

I've tried googling and found only one SO question that didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TYPO3 v8 QueryBuilder WHERE IN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057973/typo3-v8-querybuilder-where-in-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should try to avoid subselects if not needed. Your query can be written with a single SQL statement

```sql
SELECT
  * 
FROM base
JOIN table ON base.uid = table.uid_local
```

If you must combine subselects, you can do this:

```php
// Create two QueryBuilder instances, one for the subselect and one for main.
$queryBuilderSub = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
  ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table');
$queryBuilderMain = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
  ->getQueryBuilderForTable('base');

// Formulate the sub-query
$subQuery = $queryBuilderSub->select('uid_local')->from('table');

// Perform mainquery, retriev subselect as SQL string:
$result = $queryBuilderMain
  ->select('*')
  ->where(
    $queryBuilderMain->expr()->in('uid', $subQuery->getSQL()),
  )
  ->executeQuery();
```

Note: If you want to use placeholder, you need to use named placeholders and using the most outer querybuilder `$queryBuilder` for placeholder in the subQueries - otherwise this won't work.